# android - SharedPreferences persistin after clear data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

One of my clients told me something today and yeah, I'm 99% sure this is a mistake but made me think about it.

He told me He did clear the data and unistall the application from his phone, but after install again the data of the last login restore.

I know about `android:allowBackup="false"` but only in case of unistall without clear data, right?

Is it possible SharedPreferences resist a clear data?

Comment: SharedPreferences I dont think, but if the app is connected to an server is possible to restore.

Comment: Shared preferences will always be wiped with clear data. You should think about using file storage or network/API if your client needs the data to persist that far.

Comment: yup..same thing happen to me when client report that issue..device samsung..  clear the data and uninstall the application from his phone, but after install again the data of the last login restore.. some how the device it self may different settings..

Comment: No, he dont need. Its correct dont persist in that case. Its just bothering me to know if he was right or just a mistaken @BrunoFerreira

Comment: @ZeroOne hmmm, I think its a Samsung too. This `allowBackup` thing to false did the job?

Comment: when he is installing it, is it he uninstalling it for all users? I found when I un-installed from the home screen with multiple users, and I re-installed from ADB data was persisted. In order to fully clear it you have to do it from the settings. Could this be it?

Comment: Maybe, but in this case clear data from setting will clear for all user right? @RobVoisey

Comment: I asked about his device, and he told me that is a Moto G2 with Android 6.0 @ZeroOne

Comment: One of our testers claimed that in order to fully restart the test they had to uninstall it otherwise data would persist. I can't remember if this included SharedPreferences however or just the sql tables. I think the device was a Nexus 9 tablet on Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Is `android:allowBackup` set to false or to true?

If you clear the data and then *directly* uninstall the app, those changes might not be synced to the google cloud, and thus you will receive an *old* state when reinstalling the app.

Comment: Is set to `false`.  I didnt know about synced with cloud, but its a good point. There`s a way to prevent this ?